# Finding all values of variables to satisfy being a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

could someone point me in the right direction on how to go about solving this question? I need to find the values of $x,y,z$ such that $(1,x,x^2),(1,y,y^2),(1,z,z^2)$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Thanks!

Comment: do you know what the determinant of the matrix of those three vectors tells you?

Comment: We haven't done anything linking basis/determinant, so, I'm not sure what we can say here.

Comment: Well you just have to find $x,y,z$ so that the vectors are linearly independent, then since you have three linearly independent vectors in a space of dimension $3$ this will be a basis

Comment: I think we have to find all x,y,z that satisfy this.

Answer (score 1):

To be  a basis three vectors will have to be linearly independent;

so let $c_1(1,x,x^2)+c_2(1,y,y^2)+c_3(1,z,z^2)=0$

from here get the three equations ;

$c_1+c_2+c_3=0;$
$c_1x+c_2y_+c_3z=0;
c_1x^2+c_2y^2+c_3z^2=0$

Now since the vectors are linearly independent only solution you can have is $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$

Now consider the system of three equations as variables $c_1,c_2,c_3$

Thus co-efficient determinant not equal to zero .Compute the determinant it will be $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ which will be non-zero whenever $x\neq y\neq z$

Thus choosing $x\neq y\neq z$ will give a basis

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without determinants?

Comment: yes try to eliminate $c_1,c_2,c_3$ from the 3 equations and that is equivalent of finding determinant

Comment: But when you say that the determinant being non-zero implies being a basis, where does this come from? If the determinant is non-zero does this imply linear independence? We haven't covered that.

Comment: determinant non-zero implies linear independence and since any 3 l.i vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ implies it is a basis problem is solved

Comment: But how can I show this without using the determinant?

Comment: You can use the reduced row echelon form of the augmented matrix for the "three equations" mentioned above, if you like.